# Lotus Symphony - Open document in new window

Tags: macos, spreadsheet, lotus-symphony

Does anyone know how to open a document in a new window instead of a new tab in Lotus Symphony?  I would like to compare two spreadsheets and can not figure out a way to display them side by side.  I am using v1.3.0 on a Mac.  Thanks!

Comment: I am almost certain that this is not possible using the standalone version of Symphony.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right.  Oh well...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply Right Click on the Lotus Symphony Document/Spreadsheet/Presentation list at the bottom right and select `Always Open in New Window` on all or some. It is that simple. Standalone Symphony looks great and has the comfort of the Open Source Eclipse platform.

As shown here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right click on a **tab** of one of your open documents and select "open in new window" and vewala! it opens in a new window!

The other answers didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Lotus Symphony documents to now, or always, open in new windows.

Click on Open > Choose a Document Type (e.g Lotus Symphony Spreadsheet) > Choose either "Open in New Window" or Always Open in New Window.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... I don't have Open; only New.  http://flickr.com/gp/31286909@N03/2F3m20

Answer (score 0):

In Lotus Symphony version 3.0.0 it's possible to open a file in a new window by right-clicking the tab displaying the file name and selecting Open in New Window from the pop up menu.